# URL connection get input stream fails

Tags: java, http, spring-boot, url

I am trying to find the size of the directory in the server. So i have defined the class to get the access of the server and find the size:

```
public class SoftwareDownload {
  private String inputUrl;
  private String destinationPath;
  private String userName;
  private String userPassword;
  private URL url = null;
  private URLConnection uc = null;
  private String userpass;
  private String basicAuth;
  private boolean isAuthendicated = false;

  public SoftwareDownload(String inputUrl, String destinationPath, String userName, String userPassword) {
    this.inputUrl = inputUrl;
    this.destinationPath = destinationPath;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.userPassword = userPassword;
    userpass = userName + ":" + userPassword;
    basicAuth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes());
    try {
      url = new URL(this.inputUrl);
      try {
        uc = url.openConnection();
        uc.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
        isAuthendicated = true;
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("UC check nul");
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      System.out.println("Connection check nul");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }


    public long httpFindSoftwarePackage ( int count,boolean isSizeRequired) throws IOException {
    long packageByteCnt = 0;

    InputStream inStream = uc.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader streamReader=new InputStreamReader(inStream);
    BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
    String line = "";
    while(line != null) {
      line = inputStream.readLine();
      if ( (line != null ) && ( line.startsWith("<a href=")) ) {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(line);
        Element link = doc.select("a").first();
        String linkHref = link.attr("href");
        String sourceDir = inputUrl+"/"+linkHref;
        SoftwareDownload downloadimage = new SoftwareDownload (sourceDir,null,userName,userPassword);
        if( linkHref.endsWith("/") == true ) {
          packageByteCnt+=downloadimage.httpFindSoftwarePackage(count+1,isSizeRequired);
        }
        else
        {
            packageByteCnt+=downloadimage.uc.getContentLengthLong();
        }
      }
    }
    return packageByteCnt;
  }
}

Class Main:
  public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    String httpurl ="http://rb-cmbinex.com/software/rfs/16.2S813/rfs_ni";
    String destiDir = "d:/TestDirectory";
    String user = "username";
    String password = "Password#123";

    SoftwareDownload download = new SoftwareDownload(httpurl, null, user, password);

   System.out.println("Total Package Size : " + download.httpFindSoftwarePackage(0, true));
}
```

When i run this program alone i can read the size of the directory. But, in same time when i integrate this SoftwareDownload call to my spring boot java application then i got this IO exception,

java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL:http://rb-cmbinex.com/software/rfs/16.2S813/rfs_ni/rootfs/
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.bosch.boardfarm.model.SoftwareDownload.httpFindSoftwarePackage(SoftwareDownload.java:113)
    at com.bosch.boardfarm.model.SoftwareDownload.httpFindSoftwarePackage(SoftwareDownload.java:143)

Then i found that the IO exception is from the line(while geting the input stream for the connected URL),
        InputStream inStream = uc.getInputStream();

Can some one help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Is the server actually running? Firefox can't connect to your URL either. Try using a combination of `uc.getResponseCode()`, `uc.getResponseMessage()` and `uc.getErrorStream()` to figure out what actually goes wrong server side. There's a good chance that the server either isn't allowing http connection or isn't allowing directory contents to be listed.

Comment: The server is active and running.
uc.getResponseCode(), uc.getResponseMessage() and uc.getErrorStream() these options are not available in the URLConnection. 
I didn't face this problem when I run this class as a separate program. 
Suppose there is 10 directory, i am able to traverse firt 5 direcotry , the exception got randomly while travering the 6 to 10 direcotry.

Answer (score 0):

A 500 error means:

> 500 Internal Server Error
>
> A generic error message, given when an unexpected condition was encountered and no more specific message is suitable.

In short, something is wrong with the server you are trying to talk to.  You may be able to get some more information by reading and printing out the contents of the error stream.  However, it could be empty, or a "generic" error page that provides no useful information.

---

> The server is active and running.

You know this because ..... ?  (When I tried to talk to the server, I just got a timeout.)

If this is your server, check the log files to see if there are log messages corresponding to the code 500 responses.  (You may want to increase the logging level temporarily ...)

> `uc.getResponseCode()`, `uc.getResponseMessage()` and `uc.getErrorStream()` these options are not available in the URLConnection

Cast the connection to `HttpURLConnection`, and then you can call those methods.

> I didn't face this problem when I run this class as a separate program. Suppose there is 10 directory, i am able to traverse first 5 directory , the exception got randomly while traversing the 6 to 10 directory.

This suggests a couple of possibilities:

- Perhaps your requests are causing a temporary overload, and it is causing internal errors.
- Perhaps your requests are causing a temporary overload, and the server is responding with 500 responses to cause you to slow down.  (A 503 would be a more appropriate response in this case.)
- Perhaps this response is a behavior that is designed to deter web scrapers!!
- Perhaps there is a load balancer sending requests to a number of servers, and one of them is (currently) not working properly.

Comment: Response code and message I got is 500 and "Internal Server Error" respectively.

Comment: If really server overloaded, i didn't get this error when i run this code as separate program. But, when i use this code in my spring boot application(and this is the ajax .post method function) exception raised.

Comment: You previously said that you are running the program once from the command line and many times within Spring.  "Many times" suggests that >> you << are overloading the server.

Comment: OK.  So you think it is SpringBoot's fault.  So capture the requests sent over the wire in the two different cases and work out what the difference between them is.

Comment: I think you have enough to work on.  You simply need to examine all of the available evidence carefully and logically ... and avoid jumping to conclusions that are not supported by the evidence.

Comment: this is the error stream,
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@1a4f4d93

Comment: I not moving towards the conclusions rather then i am trying to understand the cause for this problem. Any how thanks for your support

Comment: Yea .. you need to read the data from the stream ... and print it.